# Force SUM method to return NULL when applicable in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.2

I'm performing a query in which I occasionally expect NULL like this:

```
.Where(d => d.Id == varid && d.Date >= vardate1 && d.Date <= vardate2)
.Sum(d => (decimal?)d.Delta);
```

Delta is a non-nullable decimal and intellisense shows that the result of the Sum is going to be a decimal? because I introduced the cast. The generated SQL is as expected, and when run manually it correctly returns NULL when there are no matching records. However, the result from the materialized query is always 0. This behavior is different than the non-core EF, which would have returned null. Is this really the new expected behavior? If so, how can I force it to return null when I need it to? Null and 0 have different meanings in this context.

I can bring in the records first and then sum on the server, but it would be nice if EF core did what I would expect on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely a bug, but knowing EF Core designer visions for non nullable `Max` / `Min` / `Average` and also `First` / `Single` translation, I won't be surprised if they are doing that intentionally to emulate the (weird) LINQ to Objects nullable `Sum` behavior which returns `0` event though the result type of the method is nullable.

It can be seen by the following snippet

```
decimal? result = Enumerable.Empty<decimal?>().Sum(); // result is 0
```

and is even [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Nullable_System_Decimal___) (!?):

> **Remarks**
>
> This method returns zero if `source` contains no elements.

The "funny" thing is that this is just for root query `Sum` execution - inside projections it has the SQL behavior you are looking for.

Which lead us to the workaround by utilizing *group by constant* trick combined with projection. In order to not repeat it everywhere you need it, and also easily remove it if it get fixed in some later EF Core version, you can encapsulate it in a custom extension method like this:

```
public static partial class EfCoreExtensions
{
    public static decimal? SumOrDefault<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, decimal?>> selector)
        => source.GroupBy(e => 0, selector).Select(g => g.Sum()).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and replace

```
.Sum(d => (decimal?)d.Delta);
```

with

```
.SumOrDefault(d => d.Delta);
```

Just make sure you use it only for final calls, because if you use it inside query expression tree, as any custom method it won't be recognized and will cause client evaluation or runtime exception.

Comment: This would require doing the SUM on the objects in memory not at the database, which potentially means returning lots more data from the database.

I think its crazy that when SQL returns NULL, EF decides to convert this to Zero without anyway of us having control over what we want returned

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to work regardless on EF Core 5.0

Answer (score 0):

The above "*group by constant trick*" does not work in EF Core 5.0.

A variation of the extension method using an Aggregate function can achieve the desired result.
So to have all NULLs return Null, but otherwise return the sum of non null values:

```
    public static decimal? SumOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal?> selector)
        => (from s in source select selector(s))
           .Aggregate((decimal?)null, (acc, item) => acc.HasValue ? acc + item.GetValueOrDefault() : item);
```

Or if you prefer that any NULL value results in a NULL returned

```
    public static decimal? SumAllOrNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal?> selector)
        => (from s in source select selector(s))
           .Aggregate((decimal?)null, (acc, item) => acc.HasValue ? acc + item : item.HasValue ? item : null);
```

But note that as mentioned, this will work only on Linq-to-Objects, not Linq-to-Sql, so you need ToList() or AsEnumerable() beforehand, and so it brings more data back from the database that you might want or need.

```
.Where(d => d.Id == varid && d.Date >= vardate1 && d.Date <= vardate2)
.AsEnumerable()
.SumOrDefault(d => d.Delta);
```